# hexcode for images in iphone

Tags: iphone, image

is it possible to store image in the form of hexcode to database

as i  have my database loacally now my app is working fine but still i am calling images from web as i cant store all images to locally so whats the best way to call those 2000 images?? directly form web or some encoding ??

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to display a large number of photos from a network data source, check out TTPhotoViewController, which is part of the [Three20 library](http://github.com/facebook/three20). It also supports incremental loading so that images are loaded as the user scrolls, and all 2000 images aren't loaded at once.